# I need to prove that $\langle n \mathbb{Z},m\rangle =\langle m\mathbb{Z},n\rangle =d\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $n, m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d=gcd(n,m)$, prove that:

$$\langle n \mathbb{Z},m\rangle =\langle m\mathbb{Z},n\rangle =d\mathbb{Z}$$

What is $\langle n\mathbb{Z},m\rangle$ here? The intersection of all the ideals that contain $m$ and $n\mathbb{Z}$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. It is the smallest ideal containing $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $m$. We claim that this ideal is the same as $\langle d\rangle$ where $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

First since $d\min m$ and $d\mid n$, clearly $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $m$ are contained in $\langle d\rangle$. Hence $\langle n\mathbb{Z},n\rangle\subseteq \langle d\rangle$.

Conversely, by Bezout's lemma there are integers $a,b$ such that $am+bn=d$. It follows that $\langle d\rangle \subseteq \langle n\mathbb{Z},n\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this:

As $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring with identity element we can san say that:

$\langle n\mathbb{Z}, m \rangle=\{ \sum a_i x_i  + \sum b_k
m \mid a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ x_i\in n\mathbb{Z} \}$

Is it correct?

In this case any element of  $\langle n\mathbb{Z}, m \rangle$ can be written as:

$na+mb$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Because $n\mathbb{Z}$ in an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the other part is also divisible by  $m$.

Then this element $na+mb$ is divisible by $d$.

$na+mb\in d\mathbb{Z}$

$\langle n\mathbb{Z}, m \rangle \subseteq d\mathbb{Z}$

Now as $d\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ and

$na=(dk)a$ with $a,k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$m=dl$ with $l \in \mathbb{Z}$

$d\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal that contains $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{m\}$, and is subset of any ideal that contains $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{m\}$.

$\langle n\mathbb{Z}, m \rangle \supseteq d\mathbb{Z}$